# buffered reader in managed bean

Tags: java, serialization

In a web app, beans have to be serializable. I'm wanting to open a couple of streams, input and output for a device, in @PostConstruct and just leave them open. However, streams aren't serializable. So, if the bean is serialized, what happens to the streams? If I make them transient, do I have to restore them when the bean is deserialized? If so, is it as simple as checking the stream for null and then reopening them if they are null? Or, is it just better to open and close them every time I do a read or write?

Comment: If you write some code to pool your streams (in much the same way the Java web apps use connection pools to deal with database connections) you could then serialize a bean that uses a stream from a pool, and deserialize it back by just grabbing a stream from the pool again. Of course, each bean might need to keep details about the position in the stream and then fast-forward to that point upon deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better approach would be to customise serialisation, i.e. in `writeObject` you flush buffers/close streams/write some additional state/etc, so that in the `readObject` you could restore original object state.